# Is it wrong for a website layout to be generated entirely by javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a project currently and have written the entire page in Javascript.

I created a basic function:

```
create_element(parent, type, style, attributes);
```

Example Usage:

```
var container = create_element(document.body, "div", {width: "100%", height: "100%"});
var header_bar = create_element(container, "div",  {width: "100%", height: "50px"});
var title_span = create_element(header_bar, "span", {fontSize: "18px", fontFamily: "arial", color: "black"});
title_span.innerHTML = "Example Website";
```

And so on...

I use this approach for the entire layout of the website. Is there a huge disadvantage to using this method? The obvious one is that fact that there may still be people out there with JS disabled.

Is there a tangible difference in page load times if Javascript is creating and rendering the items rather than them being hard coded into the HTML?

Thanks!

TL;DR -

Created a create_element function, and use it to draw all elements onto the screen. Including the base layout for the page.

Comment: In server-side JavaScript such as Node.js, you'd be required to use JS to render the layout, but that's not the question you're asking.

Comment: you may end up with the code that's very hard to maintain

Comment: What are the benefits of your approach?

Comment: Benefits might be non existent. I enjoy using just javascript rather than coupling it with html and interacting with screen elements by way of the id tag. Also, I find coding in javascript is a more enjoyable experience than writing html. If that increases my odds of finishing a project then I suppose that could be considered a personal benefite :)

Comment: Well if a user comes with noscript or JavaScript disabled, your site will be a blank screen of nothingness. If a web spider does not use JavaScript, it will index nothing.

Comment: @george-stocker can you please comment on the specific reasons you closed this question, despite the fact that there are many people interested in discussing it?

Comment: @BT You said it yourself. There aren't any answers to this question in as much as there is *discussion* around it. If you feel this closure was in error, you can flag it for reopening or bring it up on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: @george-stocker As you can see by my reputation, I can't in fact flag this question for reopening. Would you mind pointing me somewhere that defines SO's policy around closing down questions whose answers involve the compilation of information rather than simple answers?

Comment: @BT Everything you want (active policy) wise is on meta. I think you'll get a more targeted reason if you go to meta and ask about this question, but here are just some links: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34625/ http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127212/ http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55965/ http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1999/ and finally, the canonical help-center post on what not to ask: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask (didn't exist in this form at the time I closed this question, but the idea is the same).

Comment: @BT I said you should "flag" for re-opening, not "Vote" for re-opening Those are two different things. If you flag it for re-opening, it goes into a queue where users who have enough reputation to re-open can decide whether it should be re-opened or stay closed. If you click on the "flag" option, you should see what I'm referring to.

Comment: @george-stocker Thanks for all the information, I'll read up. It looks to me, based on the dont-ask page, that this question actually isn't one of the questions it's saying not to ask. It fulfills all of the criteria of a constructive question that page puts forth. I'll take your advice and flag it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a number of issues that you'll run into when you try to dynamically generate non-dynamic content:

1. Maintainability will become very difficult. If you want to make a sweeping change to your site, you're going to have to edit JS rather than just changing CSS or some HTML.
2. SEO - Google can't index dynamic data. This is not good if you want your site to be found via search engines.
3. You are mixing your layers. By not separating concerns (your views vs. your content vs. ...), you, again, increase maintainability issues and create a problem for your future-self or another developer who has to touch your code in the future.

Now, it's not wrong to do some dynamic generation - but do it appropriately. I would highly advise against dynamically generating content for your entire site.

**Update Based on Comments on Original Question**

That's great you enjoy JS. And, I definitely agree that HTML can be a bit boring. But, if you are properly separating your concerns, you really should have to write very little HTML and can quickly get back to what you enjoy coding in. But, be careful that you are not trying to force fit a language into something it was not meant to do when another language was created to do it perfectly. (Hammer/Nail Rule)

Also, don't forget that HTML5 and CSS3 is extremely powerful. You can do a lot with it and never have to even touch JS (assuming that meets client needs).

Comment: "I would highly advise dynamically generating content for your entire site." Typo?

Comment: Thanks JasCav. Exactly the type of answer I was looking for.

Comment: 1. Why would changing CSS or HTML be easier for making sweeping changes than JS? You provide 0 information to justify that. 2. SEO - that is a good point, but many application-style sites don't need it for most of their stuff. 3. You can easily separate concerns in javascript, this is not a good point

Comment: @BT - 1. You can completely change CSS structure and totally redesign your site (separating styling...the CSS...and the functionality...the JS). So, that is what I mean by that. (In fact, it's kind of the point of CSS.); 2. What application sites don't need SEO? 3. If you're mixing the CSS and HTML within the JS, as the original poster was doing, then...yes. Huge maintainability issue.

Comment: 1. You can certainly have similar sweeping changes done in pure javascript if done right (the author's asking if there's a way [and how] to do it right). 2. Application-style websites where there's no public content. 3. Agreed, but a good answer shouldn't tell him he's doing it wrong, it should tell him how to do it right.

Answer (score 3):

One major problem is that Google will not index any content of your site if you build it like this.

Also, this way your content, your logic and your styling will not be separated, which i think is a huge benefit if you use html / css in seperate files and a server side scripting language.

Comment: Actually if it is all in javascript, it can still be separated. That's like saying you cannot organize and separate different sections of code for an app because it is all written in Objective-C, or Java, or Ruby, etc.

Answer (score 2):

It is not wrong for an entire website to be generated by javascript based on the response from server if you ensure that metadata used for rendering the page is not evaluated as a whole as this leads to security issues.

Comment: Basically he's saying: an ajax response could be an object from which you build a section of your page (a form for example). But by `not evaluated as a whole` he means": don't use `eval` and don't do something like `document.getElementById('emtpyDiv').innerHTML = this.responseText;` as the response text might contain harmful JavaScript code (leaving you at risk for XSS attacks.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it would be really better to use html as it is, if it's not dynamic content.

furthermore, having separate CSS files is more appropriate than setting it inline.

Answer (score 0):

[BackboneJS](http://backbonejs.org/) does this. You just have to ensure that JS is used client-side to complliment server side rendering, and that any rendering done solely on the client is capable of being in whole or part on the server as well.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason that a pages contents couldn't entirely be generated by javascript, but I wouldn't endorse this element by element approach.  You aren't even using any style rules, only inline styles.  Furthermore, in this case it'd be more maintainable to use some sort of templating mechanism for blocks of html, such as used in Underscore.js.  (There are many templating solutions out there, like Mustache and Handlebars; I'm just giving one I've used.)  There are several ways to maintain the html without it being in some javascript file somewhere, but even if it *were* in a javascript file, it'd be more maintainable than this element by element business.